# Preserve the aspect ratio of Image in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

How to preserve the aspect ratio of the image loaded onto the canvas? When the image is loaded from local system onto the canvas I'm creating image object with `width=canvas.width` and `height=canvas.height`.

But the quality is missing. Even if loaded image resolution is higher. Is there any way to preserve the aspect ratio of the loaded image?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You lose aspect ratio because you se _both_ width and height to those of canvas (if the canvas has different aspect ratio than an image).

Comment: I mean autofit an image when loaded onto the canvas with quality. As of now it is skewed,stretched.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but did you find any solution @John, I am running through the same problems?? But I am not trying to set a background with the image, merely adding objects inside the canvas.

Answer (score 15):

Did I get it right: you want to fill the canvas with the image, keep the ratio and hide the overflow?

You should recalculate them:

`cw`, `ch` - canvas dimensions

`iw`, `ih` - image dimensions

```
ih = imgObj.naturalHeight;
iw = imgObj.naturalWidth;
```

`fw`, `fh` - final dimensions

```
width_ratio  = cw  / iw;
height_ratio = ch / ih;
if (width_ratio > height_ratio) {
    fw = iw * width_ratio;
    fh = ih*fw/iw;
} else {
    fh = ih * height_ratio;
    fw = iw*fh/ih;    
}
```

Then just feed options like this

```
var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
image.set({
    width:fw,
    height:fh
});

canvas.add(image);
```